# How to use ThemeManager in code behinde

Tags: xaml, mahapps.metro

I'm new in mahapps.metro Themes . when i used ThemeManager it works just once and then in second use it rise an null reference exception . for example first i select Blue Theme it works but When after that i select green theme  it not work and rise a null reference Exception .
here is a sample code :

```
ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(Application.Current,
                                    ThemeManager.GetAccent("Blue"),
                                    ThemeManager.GetAppTheme("BaseDark"));
 ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(Application.Current,
                                    ThemeManager.GetAccent("Green"),
                                    ThemeManager.GetAppTheme("BaseDark"));
```

what is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

This lines should work at this point in App.xaml code behind or at your main Window constructor.

```
using System.Windows;
using MahApps.Metro;

namespace MetroDemo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);
            ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(Application.Current,
                                        ThemeManager.GetAccent("Blue"),
                                        ThemeManager.GetAppTheme("BaseDark"));
            ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(Application.Current,
                                        ThemeManager.GetAccent("Green"),
                                        ThemeManager.GetAppTheme("BaseDark"));
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure you are adding the necessary resources to the App.xaml, cause you want to change the resources of your App!

```
<Application x:Class="MetroDemo.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <!-- MahApps.Metro resource dictionaries. Make sure that all file names are Case Sensitive! -->
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
        <!-- Accent and AppTheme setting -->
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Hope this helps.